# Constraints by overflow-y: scroll

Tags: css

I have a situation where I have a dropdown (a) inside a dropdown (b) etc for a possible 5 levels.

Dropdown (a) is way to tall to fit into the screen, so I applied a `overflow-y:scroll` and a `height of 450px` which works well on the dropdown (a)

But when I open a sub or contained dropdown inside dropdown (a) and it is longer than 450px (which is the height of (a)) it does not show the entire dropdown (b).

I understand that this is how it probably should work, but I need a work around and I dont know enough of css to create this.

In the example bellow Admission in Dropdown (a)
and caller is dropdown (b) which you can see from my art work is dropping off the bottom of the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Max-height in conjunction with height will usually do the trick.

Comment: Please paste your CSS and HTML code here or create Fiddle for same. An image won't help us to evaluate exact issue in your code. I hope you are not using "position" property for sub-menu dropdown,

Answer (score 0):

```
max-height
```

css property instead of height.